# Need help in creating a function to plot a Matplotlib GridSpec

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have a dataset with 80 variables. I am interested in creating a function that will automate the creation of a 20 X 4 GridSpec in Matplotlib. Each subplot would either contain a histogram or a barplot for each of the 80 variables in the data. As a first step, I successfully created two functions (I call them 'counts' and 'histogram') that contain the layout of the plot that I want. Both of them work when tested on individual variables. As a next step, I attempted to create a function that would take the column names, loop through a conditional to test whether the data type is an object or otherwise and call the right function based on the datatype as a new subplot. Here is the code that I have so far:

## Creates list of coordinates we will need for subplot specification:

```
A = np.arange(21)
B = np.arange(4)
coords = []
    
for i in A:
    for j in B:
        coords.append([A[i], B[j]])

#Create the gridspec and layout the figure
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,6))
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2,4)

#Function that relies on what we've done above:
def grid(cols=['MSZoning', 'LotFrontage', 'LotArea', 'Street', 'Alley']):
    for i in cols:
        for vals in coords:
            if str(train[i].dtype) == 'object':
                plt.subplot('gs'+str(vals))
                counts(cols)
            else:
                plt.subplot('gs'+str(vals))
                histogram(cols)
```

When attempted, this code returns an error:

ValueError: Single argument to subplot must be a 3-digit integer

For purposes of helping you visualize, what I am hoping to achieve, I attach the screen shot below, which was produced by the line by line coding (with my created helper functions) I am trying to avoid:
[image]

Can anyone help me figure out where I am going wrong? I would appreciate any advice. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The line `plt.subplot('gs'+str(vals))` cannot work; which is also what the error tells you.

As can be seen from the matplotlib [GridSpec tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html#gridspec-and-subplotspec), it needs to be

```
ax = plt.subplot(gs[0, 0])
```

So in your case you may use the values from the list as

```
ax = plt.subplot(gs[vals[0], vals[1]])
```

Mind that you also need to make sure that the `coords` list must have the `n*m` elements, if the gridspec is defined as `gs = gridspec.GridSpec(n,m)`.